# How do I add an external font into an iframe that uses CSS within JavaScript to customize it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify, font-face

I am trying to integrate Shopify's buy button into my website, and I want the fonts of the product info to fit into the theme of the rest of my website. Here's solely the code that Shopify provided to me to integrate the products themselves into the page as a collection:

```
          <div id='collection-component-12683f1cb13'></div>
          <script type="text/javascript">
          /*<![CDATA[*/

          (function () {
            var scriptURL = 'https://sdks.shopifycdn.com/buy-button/latest/buy-button-storefront.min.js';
            if (window.ShopifyBuy) {
              if (window.ShopifyBuy.UI) {
                ShopifyBuyInit();
              } else {
                loadScript();
              }
            } else {
              loadScript();
            }

            function loadScript() {
              var script = document.createElement('script');
              script.async = true;
              script.src = scriptURL;
              (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(script);
              script.onload = ShopifyBuyInit;
            }

            function ShopifyBuyInit() {
              var client = ShopifyBuy.buildClient({
                domain: 'crystal-cave-costa-mesa.myshopify.com',
                storefrontAccessToken: 'c5373f1d38c5cc83403cbadb8e81bf98',
              });

              ShopifyBuy.UI.onReady(client).then(function (ui) {
                ui.createComponent('collection', {
                  id: 138231152743,
                  node: document.getElementById('collection-component-12683f1cb13'),
                  moneyFormat: '%24%7B%7Bamount%7D%7D',
                  options: {
        "product": {
          "buttonDestination": "modal",
          "variantId": "all",
          "isButton": false,
          "contents": {
            "imgWithCarousel": false,
            "variantTitle": false,
            "options": false,
            "description": false,
            "buttonWithQuantity": false,
            "quantity": false
          },
          "text": {
            "button": "View Product"
          },
          "styles": {
            "product": {
              "@media (min-width: 601px)": {
                "max-width": "calc(33.33333% - 30px)",
                "margin-left": "30px",
                "margin-bottom": "50px",
                "width": "calc(33.33333% - 30px)"
              },
              "imgWrapper": {
                "position": "relative",
                "height": "0",
                "padding-top": "calc(75% + 15px)"
              },
              "img": {
                "height": "calc(100% - 15px)",
                "position": "absolute",
                "left": "0",
                "right": "0",
                "top": "0"
              }
            },
            "button": {
              "background-color": "#0e72b5",
              "font-family": "BoydUncial !important",
              ":hover": {
                "background-color": "#0d67a3"
              },
              "border-radius": "5px",
              ":focus": {
                "background-color": "#0d67a3"
              },
              "font-weight": "normal"
            },
            "variantTitle": {
              "font-family": "BoydUncial !important",
              "font-weight": "normal"
            },
            "title": {
              "font-family": "BoydUncial !important",
              "font-weight": "normal",
              "color": "#5b0580"
            },
            "description": {
              "color": "#5b0580",
              "font-size": "15px",
              "font-family": "BoydUncial !important",
              "font-weight": "normal"
            },
            "price": {
              "font-family": "BoydUncial !important",
              "color": "#5b0580",
              "font-weight": "normal"
            },
            "compareAt": {
              "color": "#5b0580",
              "font-family": "BoydUncial !important",
              "font-weight": "normal"
            }
          }
        },
        "cart": {
          "contents": {
            "button": true
          },
          "text": {
            "title": "Your Cart",
            "button": "Checkout"
          },
          "styles": {
            "button": {
              "background-color": "#0e72b5",
              "font-family": "BoydUncial !important",
              ":hover": {
                "background-color": "#0d67a3"
              },
              "border-radius": "5px",
              ":focus": {
                "background-color": "#0d67a3"
              },
              "font-weight": "normal"
            },
            "title": {
              "color": "#5b0580"
            },
            "footer": {
              "background-color": "#ffffff"
            },
            "header": {
              "color": "#5b0580"
            },
            "lineItems": {
              "color": "#5b0580"
            },
            "subtotalText": {
              "color": "#5b0580"
            },
            "subtotal": {
              "color": "#5b0580"
            },
            "notice": {
              "color": "#5b0580"
            },
            "currency": {
              "color": "#5b0580"
            },
            "close": {
              ":hover": {
                "color": "#5b0580"
              },
              "color": "#5b0580"
            },
            "emptyCart": {
              "color": "#5b0580"
            }
          }
        },
        "modalProduct": {
          "contents": {
            "img": false,
            "imgWithCarousel": true,
            "variantTitle": false,
            "buttonWithQuantity": true,
            "button": false,
            "quantity": false
          },
          "text": {
            "button": "Add to Cart"
          },
          "styles": {
            "product": {
              "@media (min-width: 601px)": {
                "max-width": "100%",
                "margin-left": "0px",
                "margin-bottom": "0px"
              }
            },
            "button": {
              "background-color": "#0e72b5",
              "font-family": "BoydUncial !important",
              ":hover": {
                "background-color": "#0d67a3"
              },
              "border-radius": "5px",
              ":focus": {
                "background-color": "#0d67a3"
              },
              "font-weight": "normal"
            },
            "variantTitle": {
              "font-family": "BoydUncial !important",
              "font-weight": "normal"
            },
            "title": {
              "font-family": "BoydUncial !important",
              "font-weight": "normal",
              "color": "#5b0580"
            },
            "description": {
              "color": "#5b0580",
              "font-size": "15px",
              "font-family": "BoydUncial !important",
              "font-weight": "normal"
            },
            "price": {
              "font-family": "BoydUncial !important",
              "color": "#5b0580",
              "font-weight": "normal"
            },
            "compareAt": {
              "font-size": "15.299999999999999px",
              "font-family": "BoydUncial !important",
              "font-weight": "normal"
            }
          }
        },
        "toggle": {
          "styles": {
            "toggle": {
              "font-family": "BoydUncial !important",
              "background-color": "#0e72b5",
              ":hover": {
                "background-color": "#0d67a3"
              },
              ":focus": {
                "background-color": "#0d67a3"
              },
              "font-weight": "normal"
            },
            "count": {
              "font-size": "16px"
            }
          }
        },
        "option": {
          "styles": {
            "label": {
              "font-family": "BoydUncial !important"
            },
            "select": {
              "font-family": "BoydUncial !important"
            }
          }
        },
        "productSet": {
          "styles": {
            "products": {
              "font-family": "BoydUncial !important",
              "@media (min-width: 601px)": {
                "margin-left": "-30px"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "lineItem": {
          "styles": {
            "variantTitle": {
              "color": "#5b0580"
            },
            "title": {
              "color": "#5b0580"
            },
            "price": {
              "color": "#5b0580"
            },
            "quantity": {
              "color": "#5b0580"
            },
            "quantityIncrement": {
              "color": "#5b0580",
              "border-color": "#5b0580"
            },
            "quantityDecrement": {
              "color": "#5b0580",
              "border-color": "#5b0580"
            },
            "quantityInput": {
              "color": "#5b0580",
              "border-color": "#5b0580"
            }
          }
        }
      }
                });
              });
            }
          })();
          /*]]>*/
          </script>
```

The font was originally set to "Arial", so I found and replaced the 16 instances of "Arial" with "BoydUncial". This font is the one that's used for all the paragraph text on the rest of my website, and I already have a link to my CSS document that has the following code in it to identify this external font:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "BoydUncial";
  src: url(boydun.ttf);
}
```

This is why I don't understand why writing

`"font-family": "BoydUncial !important"`

within the script's CSS doesn't allow the font to display within the product info. I tried other things also, such as opening a `<style>` in the `<head>` of the page and identifying the font using `@font-face`. Also, I tried adding the `@font-face` code into the script itself, but that breaks the iframe completely and nothing displays.

So my question exactly is, how and where do I write my `@font-face` code so that the font "BoydUncial" is identified and displays in the product info?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That Shopify code creates an iframe and embeds the button inside. You cannot style code inside an iframe unless you have access to the page.

However, Shopify allows you to have the code embedded without an iframe now.

https://shopify.github.io/buy-button-js/advanced/

```
var options = {
  product: {
    iframe: false
  },
  cart: {
    iframe: false
  }
}
```

You will have to style everything in your CSS; the styles in the object will be ignored.